# BerkeleyDB getting fat and slow

Tags: c, database, berkeley-db

i'm trying to add 3e9 keys(with low repetition) to a BerkeleyDB at 50k per-second insertions, with composite records formed by a struct with two integers. Each key have length 30. I'm using C API.

Looks like i have to increase cache_size to 2GB, otherwise insertion on database gets extremely slow after some time. However, it always consume more than 2GB on RAM.

I don't use transactions or cursors and i'm using DB_HASH.

How to have sure that i won't consume so much RAM and won't get too slow?

Comment: 3 _billion_ keys?! At 50k per second, that's almost 17 hours to insert.

Comment: There is a big increase performance if you work with a solid state drive (SSD), in wich OS? if you are under some unix you can take a look to noatime http://tldp.org/LDP/solrhe/Securing-Optimizing-Linux-RH-Edition-v1.3/chap6sec73.html

Comment: @DavidRF If i work with SSD i will write to DB much faster than 50k per second, but this isn't exacly importante since my app doesn't generates data so fast.

Comment: @MattBall yeah, this isn't a fast task =P

Answer (score 0):

BerekelyDB honors user settings fro RAM use, and will use as much RAM as permitted/configured.
Configure a lower value if you wish to use less RAM.

Meanwhile the S-L-O-W while creating/inserting may be due to fsync(2) calls that BerkeleyDB makes to ensure that new data is on disk after db->put.

You can speed up BerkeleyDB by overriding the fsync(2) vector with a noop routine
(i.e. just return success but do nothing) when you are creating the database and
don't really care whether the data has been flushed to disk yet.